# How to create DirectoryEntry for specific group

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to get `DirectoryEntry` object for e.g. Domain-Users group. I'm following [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to remove user from a certain group.

```
strGroup = "CN=TestGroup,OU=TestOU";    
objGroup = objADAM.Children.Find(strGroup, "group");
```

This code is from MSDN example. If I find my group in Active Directory Users and Computers applet, which is CN and OU?

EDIT:
To be more general, where do I find this name for `Find` method?

From MSDN:

> name
>   Type: System.String
>   The name of the child directory object for which to search.

Is this the distinguished name or else?

Comment: Have a look at my [Beavertail ADSI Browser](http://adsi.mvps.org/adsi/CSharp/beavertail.html) - it shows you the AD hierarchy and all the relevant info for the LDAP paths etc.

Comment: Is `strGroup` the distinguished name? Something like `CN=Domain-Users,CN=Users,DC=test1` ?

Comment: the "name" should really be the "local" name of the object inside its container. So it might be `CN=TestGroup` inside the `OU=TestOU` container - or something else. It's just the local, distinguished name of the object you're looking for - just the local name, *not* the whole long LDAP path....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two separate environments that share a significant amount of overlap.  DirectoryEntry is part of the DirectoryServices package, GetObject is a VBA tool that interfaces with ActiveDs.dll.

If this needs to be visual basic script then you have the equivalent of a DirectoryEntry from GetObject() or the Find() method.  If you need access to properties use the object.Get("property_name") method (returns an array for multivalued attributes)

If you can swap development platform to something .NET, you'll have access to all the DirectoryServices you want.

EDIT: If this is a C# .NET app, here's the code to use

```
private static DirectoryEntry getGroupDE(String group)
{
    String adserver = "dc.companyname.com";
    String searchroot = "ou=Groups,dc=companyname,dc=com";
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
    ds.SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(String.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}",adserver,searchroot));
    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    ds.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=group)(sAMAccountName={0}))",group);
    SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
    if (sr == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
}
```

Comment: No, this is a part of .NET application in C#

Comment: If this is .NET and C# I would use DirectorySearcher.  Let me add some code to the above post for you.